# xlwings Screen still Updates When screen_updating Off

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

I have 10-12 xlwings fairly complicated xlwings live writes I'd like to do.  If possible, I'd like to have them appear simultaneously.  I've also read that turning [screen_updating off might speed up the writes](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html) which would be nice.

However, I must be making a mistake on implementation as the below sample code you can see the writes happen one at a time if you watch closely.  For my bigger DataFrame writes this is more noticeable.

```
book = apps.active.books[_FILE]
sheet = book.sheets['Sheet1']

book.app.screen_updating = False
for i in range(100):
    sheet.range(f'A{i+2}').value = 'VALUE'

book.app.screen_updating = True
```

Comment: xlwings v0.15.10, python 3.7, Windows 10 Pro

Comment: `ScreenUpdating` turns off Excel screen updating *while a macro is running*. But an `xlwings` command is (from Excel's point of view) a one-line macro. So even if `ScreenUpdating` is off, the moment your `xlwings` call returns, you will see a screen update. Consider rewriting your code as follows: build a list of the 100 new values and update `screen.range` with all 100 values in a single call. I suspect that (as a side benefit) it might be much faster.

Comment: Interesting.  So the actual code writes 10 or so Pandas DataFrames on various parts of multiple sheets.  Rather than the call above which could easily be combined into a single Series call.  So the conclusion here is I would have to combine the DataFrame calls?  Likely not realistic in this case, unfortunately.  Good to know though.

Comment: Would turning screen updating off in VBA before running the script from a button work?

Comment: My comment was based on your (understandably and commendably stripped-down) sample code. To solve your real problem you may have to bite the bullet and write a VBA macro that does what you want, and call that in a single `xlwings` call. I freely admit I would hate to have to do that. As an alternative, a technique I have found helpful is such situations is to have spreadsheets A and B. You update A (invisible) via COM, and B just reports what is in A. You can control when B updates from A.

Comment: The multiple sheet solution is interesting.  Your idea suggests that I could build a VBA script that turns off updating, calls the python script and turns back on updating.  Not sure if that would still count as multiple macro calls or not...